# Google Cloud Committed User Discounts

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I'm running a GCP Compute Engine instance with 4 CPUS and 15 GB of memory with a cost of, lets say for this example, USD 100/month.
If i purchase a 'Committed Use Discount' of the same spec as above, do i need to apply it to the VM or the system will automatically know where is the use discount supposed to be used?
I'm only asking because you cannot cancel these things after you make the purchase.

Answer (score 0):

After you purchase a commitment, you'll set your machine specs by following [these steps](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/signing-up-committed-use-discounts#purchasecommitment). As you can see, you'll choose a machine type, the quantities of vCPU and memory as it will be a new instance.